# Let S be a subset of a general metric space. Is it true that if S is connected then the closure of S equals to the derived set of S?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let S be a subset of a general metric space. Is it true that if S is connected then the closure of S equals to the derived set of S?

I am not sure that does the equality hold?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.com, could you provide more info of what do you mean by $S$? It is a topological space? A subset of the real numbers?

Comment: Sorry, S is a subset of a general matric space.

Comment: To improve your question, edit your post by incorporating that comment into your post. That way you will avoid later readers who don't know what $S$ is and give you a close vote without bothering to read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Metric spaces are $T_1$, and points are closed.

A basic result is that the closure of a connected set is connected.

Now if there is $x\in\bar S$ such that $x\not\in S'$, then there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\cap S\setminus\{x\}=\emptyset$.  This implies $U\cap \bar S\setminus\{x\}=\emptyset$.

Then ${x}$ is clopen in $\bar S$.  So $\bar S=\{x\}\cup \bar S\setminus\{x\}$ is disconnected.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\{x\}$ is open from $U\cap\overline S\setminus\{x\}=\varnothing$?

Comment: @Math1000 $U\cap\overline S\setminus\{x\}=\varnothing$ implies that $U\cap\overline S=\{ x\}$ and hence $x$ is open in $\overline{S}$ (he is not saying that it is open in the metric space). Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a subset $S \subset X$, a set $V \subseteq S$ is called open in $S$ if there exists an open subset $U \subset X$ such that $V=U \cap S$.

Comment: Ah, I should have read more carefully. Indeed the answer does state "$x$ is clopen in $\overline S$". I agree, then.